# using two parameters in the url while using DeleteView

Tags: python, django

I was making a blog and I wanted the `confirm delete comment` to be on the following url route `post/<int:id>/comment/<int:pk>/` but when I do this the browser show the following error

> Reverse for 'comment' with arguments '(38,)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['post/(?P[0-9]+)/comment/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

the code to the program is given below. the reason I want to do this is to be able to redirect to the `post-detail` view after the deletion is done

views.py

```
class CommentDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = comment
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.user:
            return True
        return False
```

models.py

```
class comment(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title,str(self.user.username))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
path('post/<int:id>/comment/<int:pk>/', views.comment_detail, name='comment'),
path('post/<int:id>/comment/<int:pk>/delete', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL expects two arguments, so you need to pass two arguments to `reverse`.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={"id": self. post_id, "pk": self.pk})
```

Note that `id` and `pk` usually mean the same thing; you should probably use clearer names in the URL pattern, eg `post_id` and `comment_id`.

Comment: I did those changes yet im getting the same error the only thing that changed is instead of `39` the argument it cant find is  `''`

Comment: **NoReverseMatch at /post/27/
Reverse for 'comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/comment/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']**

Comment: You need to show the full traceback (as an edit to the question). The error is not coming from the code you have posted.